# WndProc doesn't want trigger it with Alt+Keys and LeftAlt

Tags: c#, xna

Everything is fine, but it doesn't work with ALT+Numpad(•◘○♦♣♠) and Left ALT+Numbers(¹²³£¢¬). I tired use WM_KEYDOWN and WM_SYSKEYDOWN, still didn't work.

Thanks in advance,
Cadu

Comment: aren't those key modifiers? i.e. no message sent until a key is pressed

Comment: It did sent, and I can't use TranslateMessage for WndProc

Comment: Everything is fine. What does that mean? What is your program? What is your question?

Comment: WM_CHAR does work, XNA, Trying adding ALT+keys.

Comment: You need to put some effort into writing a question. This is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

ALT, SHIFT, CTRL are among key modifiers. This means that you can press the key all you want, but no event is fired and no attention is really paid to the keys in a normal app, until a another key is pressed with it.

You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603378/how-to-capture-when-the-user-pressed-a-modifier-key) post helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: That's exactly what I said in my comment!

Comment: I'm not using Forms, i'm using XNA, only I have problem is I can't add WM_KEYDOWN(ALT) to get character like "•¿™¹²³£¢¬".