# How can I capture modifier (ctrl, alt, shift) key presses as a single key press in a C# console app?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Console.ReadKey will only capture input when a "normal" key is pressed, and then it attaches the modifiers (if any) as a part of the key info. How can I register a single modifier key press as an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is offered in [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/). I do some edit on the mentioned code for as an answer to your question.

To run this code:

1. Create a `Console Application`
2. Add reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly
3. Paste this code and test.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    class InterceptKeys
    {
        // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                OnKeyDown?.Invoke(new KeyEventArgs((Keys)vkCode));
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        private static event OnKeyDownDelegate OnKeyDown = null;
        public delegate void OnKeyDownDelegate(KeyEventArgs e);
        public static void SetupHook(OnKeyDownDelegate OnKeyDown)
        {
            InterceptKeys.OnKeyDown = OnKeyDown;
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
                Application.Run();
                UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
            });
        }

        public static void ReleaseHook()
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }

    static void KeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hook: "+ e.KeyCode);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        InterceptKeys.SetupHook(KeyDown);
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            Console.WriteLine("ReadKey: "+ key);

            if (key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                break;
        }
        InterceptKeys.ReleaseHook();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked (sort of). It still doesn't capture the ALT key presses for some reason, but it at least gets SHIFT and CTRL. I'll muddle around with it some to see if I can get it to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you in a console application?  This is WinForm code:**

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227161/18941).  Try this:

```
private void YourControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.KeyCode  == Keys.Menu)
    {
        //YourCode
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private void YourControl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Menu)
    {
        //YourCode
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Perhaps there are also modifiers for Control and Shift?  If not, I'm afraid that you'll need to use a timer and repeatedly check the state, or perhaps a global keyboard hook could catch it.

Modifier keys do not raise standard KeyPress events.