# How to read keypress using C# Console Application? (With Shift,ALT,CTRL)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

I have .NET 2.0 Console Application.

I just Want to add if else method if key was pressed within 10 seconds. Using Timer.

I want to add like this

```
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        while ((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds < 5)
        {
            if ((Console.KeyAvailable ))
            {
                var key = KeyHandler.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine($"Event:{key.KeyPressType} Key:{key.Key.Key}");
                Console.WriteLine("pressed");
                
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NOT pressed");
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
```

But Adding upside code into following code.
Program not detecting if ALT,CTRL Or Shift key pressed.

Here is working code without timers.

**I just want to stop program for 10 seconds. Detect any key was pressed or not. Resume program to next without Pressing any key.**

**This is used for bad key detection of keyboard.**

I dont want to use Thread.Sleep . Because that will block small seconds.

````````````
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using static Win32Native;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Timers;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        while (true)
        {
            var key = KeyHandler.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine($"Event:{key.KeyPressType} Key:{key.Key.Key}");
        }
    }
}

enum KeyPressType { KeyUp, KeyDown, Unknown }
class SimpleKeyRecord { public KeyPressType KeyPressType; public ConsoleKeyInfo Key; }
class KeyHandler
{
    static IntPtr _consoleInputHandle = Win32Native.GetStdHandle(Win32Native.STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    
    public static SimpleKeyRecord ReadKey()
    {
        var result = new SimpleKeyRecord();
        Win32Native.InputRecord ir;
        int numEventsRead;

        if (!Win32Native.ReadConsoleInput(_consoleInputHandle, out ir, 1, out numEventsRead) || numEventsRead == 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        if (ir.eventType != 1)  // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/input-record-str
        {
            result.KeyPressType = KeyPressType.Unknown; // Focus/Mouse/Menu event.
            return result;
        }

        result.KeyPressType = ir.keyEvent.keyDown ? KeyPressType.KeyDown : KeyPressType.KeyUp;

        ControlKeyState state = (ControlKeyState)ir.keyEvent.controlKeyState;
        bool shift = (state & ControlKeyState.ShiftPressed) != 0;
        bool alt = (state & (ControlKeyState.LeftAltPressed | ControlKeyState.RightAltPressed)) != 0;
        bool control = (state & (ControlKeyState.LeftCtrlPressed | ControlKeyState.RightCtrlPressed)) != 0;

        result.Key = new ConsoleKeyInfo((char)ir.keyEvent.uChar, (ConsoleKey)ir.keyEvent.virtualKeyCode, shift, alt, control);

        short virtualKeyCode = ir.keyEvent.virtualKeyCode;

        return result;
    }
}

class Win32Native
{
    public const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int whichHandle);
    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool ReadConsoleInput(IntPtr hConsoleInput, out InputRecord buffer, int numInputRecords_UseOne, out int numEventsRead);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct InputRecord
    {
        internal short eventType;
        internal KeyEventRecord keyEvent;
    }

    // Win32's KEY_EVENT_RECORD
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal struct KeyEventRecord
    {
        internal bool keyDown;
        internal short repeatCount;
        internal short virtualKeyCode;
        internal short virtualScanCode;
        internal char uChar; // Union between WCHAR and ASCII char
        internal int controlKeyState;
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum ControlKeyState
    {
        RightAltPressed = 0x0001,
        LeftAltPressed = 0x0002,
        RightCtrlPressed = 0x0004,
        LeftCtrlPressed = 0x0008,
        ShiftPressed = 0x0010,
        NumLockOn = 0x0020,
        ScrollLockOn = 0x0040,
        CapsLockOn = 0x0080,
        EnhancedKey = 0x0100
    }
}
```````````
````````````

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688946/how-can-i-capture-modifier-ctrl-alt-shift-key-presses-as-a-single-key-press

Comment: _".Net 2 Console Application"_ Do you mean .NET Framework or .Net Core? If it's .Net Core, you're not likely using C# 2 that you've tagged.

Comment: @phuzi : ..NET Framework 2.0

Comment: Are wanting your `KeyHandler.ReadKey` to allow only pressing of a modifier key? i.e. a single press of `Ctrl`

Comment: @phuzi : I just want to wait 10 seconds. Using DateTime.Now and check if key is pressed or not.  I dont want to wait after 10 seconds passed. I want to add if else where ANY ANY key was pressed.

Comment: @Matthew Watson : That link wont help.